# Using siunitx when submitting to APS

Tags: siunitx

Just got to know the pretty amazing `siunitx` package. I started converting all the units in my last draft for a publication, but I'm wondering now if maybe it is useless if the publisher does not support it. Publishers have there own way of typesetting units the right way, no?

So, my question. Do you know if APS supports this package? And in particular PRL and PRB? And what about other journals in general?

Comment: APS prefers if you use `REVTeX`. The best way to find out about compatibility issues is to send an e-mail to `mis@aps.org`.

Comment: You may also want to compare the outputs of `siunitx` against [this](https://authors.aps.org/STYLE/grammar.html#units). (I do believe the two are the same.)

Comment: And it is always possible to write a configuration file to adhere to their guidelines: `siunitx` is very configurable.

Comment: The main problem may well be that `siunitx` needs an up-to-date TeX system, and a lot of publishers stick with 'known' systems. I suspect that a definitive answer is only available either by asking the APS or trying it and seeing what happens!

Comment: @Willie @Joseph, I contacted the APS and will come back to you when I have more information.

Comment: @Willie @Joseph : I got the answer from APS : "APS does not support siunitx at this time.". This pretty much answers the question :)

Comment: Anybody heard anything different from APS in the four years since this question was submitted?

Comment: @KevinMorse, yes, it is different now. See Markandthequark's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently emailed APS regarding this question. They said that it *is* acceptable to use the siunitx package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8):

The APS journals use REVTeX as a somewhat-structured markup  which can be mostly-automatically imported into their [(non-TeX-based) internal system.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120271/alternatives-to-latex/120496#120496) They employ people to perform this conversion to their internal system for the tricky places where the conversion process fails (these people will reference the TeX-generated PDF in order to know what they should put in). It's very likely that the conversion scripts will not understand the siunitx commands. So, using siunitx has pros and cons:

Pros:

- You have an easier time with authoring your paper;
- People get to see nicely-formatted units in your author-prepared preprints (eg., on arXiv).

Cons:

- Your paper will take slightly longer in production before you receive your proofs;
- There is a slightly higher chance of errors being introduced in your units (due to the necessary manual intervention), meaning that you should pay close attention when you get back your proofs.

Comment: I accept this answer because it confirms what I was fearing in some way. I'll come back to this if I get a positive answer to my mail to the APS telling me their conversion scripts support `siunitx`, which seems unlikely. Thanks a lot!

Comment: see my last comment in the question.