# Alternatives to LaTeX

Tags: typography, latex-misc, big-list

Are there any  **professional** alternatives  to TeX/LaTeX which produce **equal or even better** typesetting? Maybe expensive commercial ones. The software counts if it is comparable or superior to LaTeX (with microtype) in typesetting text *or* math (or both). In any case, please mention both aspects in your answer.

I am only aware of ConTeXt (which is partly based on TeX).

Note that I am not looking for an alternative for my personal use, I am just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Without making any comparisons, there is [Adobe inDesign](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/indesign.html)

Comment: @ScottH. -- to the best of my knowledge, indesign doesn't (yet?) handle math.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for pointing that out.  I've never used it myself and, strangely, whether or not it was "math capable" never even crossed my mind.

Comment: @student Now that it has been mentioned, is math typesetting a requirement?

Comment: There is also Docscape though it is based on TeX. Ask @StephanLehmke in the chat room.

Comment: @ScottH. See my updated question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: But there is a plugin named [MathMagic](http://www.mathmagic.com/product/pro.html) for Adobe InDesign to handle math.

Comment: There is [QuarkXPress](http://www.quark.com/Products/QuarkXPress/).  I've never used it, but I believe some academic publishers do (or have done).

Comment: There is an interesting comparison LaTeX vs. InDesign (but a bit old): http://www.zinktypografie.nl/latex.php?lang=en

Comment: @mozartstraße -- thanks.  we'll have to look into it.  Xavier's answer implies that it may not be able to handle math of great complexity (which is an imperative for ams; sometimes even tex has to be hand-tuned to handle some of the stuff we get).  also, it's not clear how "author friendly" it would be; ams requires a tool that can be used "comfortably" directly by authors.

Comment: I tried MathMagic plugin with inDesign. It was terrible. It is just like using the equation editor with Word. Has to go through loops to finally enter an equation. One equation. That is it. After 10 minutes of using it, I uninstalled the whole thing, and also uninstalled indesign (was trial version). With no direct Latex support inside indesign, I mean direct support, indesign will never make it in science, math and engineering. Ok for magazines and articles. Nothing more.

Comment: Define `professional`. What’s missing in LaTeX or TeX that you need?

Comment: Why all this focus on typesetting details at cost of simplicity ? I am interested in how to compose the layout of my papers, not on how to exactly display the ending of the letter T in LaTeX..

Comment: I'm new to this stack and seeing as I don't have the 10 reputation points required I cannot answer the question. But it seems that nobody has recommended Affinity Designer. Pro tool, one-off, single purchase (unlike Adobe InDesign/CC)for a fraction of the cost of Adobe tools for professional use. Arguably as good or better than InDesign, though lacks some of the features of ID. I've used most of the pro DTP tools available for macOS for the last three decades and a bit more. I'm always urging myself to leave the Adobe racquet for Affinity and other video/audio tools but haven't managed it yet.

Comment: I wonder which kind of software is used by publishers of high school textbooks. Some of them have a lot of math (even integrals, derivatives and all sorts of complex expressions). I am an expert Latex user and I do not think that the graphical output that you see in such books (very much different from what you see in research article or even in some pure math books, I have written some) can be obtained through latex or similar. Do you know what do they use? I suspected MagicMath with InDesign (not so terrible if you use it everyday). I think you need tools such as InDesign. Maurizio

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You asked for *professional* solutions. Several top technical journals, including I believe Physical Review Letters and Nature magazine, use Advanced Print Publisher (APP), also known as Advent 3B2. Formerly available from Arbortext but now from PTC.

It can definitely handle mathematics, and I'm sure it deals with typographic details such as ligatures and microtype-like tweaks. I believe the main strength over tex is that it makes complete document production very automated. Things like dealing with floats (tables and figures) in a more-automatic way than tex, and giving manual controls to override it.

I haven't used it, however. (standard desktop version starts at US$5000-10000 as of January 2015). [The wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbortext_Advanced_Print_Publisher) has a little information.

Comment: 45,000 dollars? I wonder if they have student version?

Comment: Does Advanced Print Publisher relate to LaTeX? I ask because I know submissions to Phys. Rev. Letters can be given in LaTeX (with the revtex package).

Comment: @mrc More likely if you submit in LaTeX, they send it to some developing country to re-type everything from scratch.

Comment: @yo' that would introduce many typos (in any country). I have seen myself submitting in TeX and getting edited documents (with punctuation and grammar corrections from the editor) very much like MSWord tracked changes that would be (or was) very difficult to do with LaTeX. I guess they have a battery of (human monitored) conversion tools. LaTeX <-> Word <-> Expensive proprietary system <-> LaTeX. The final quality is always pretty good in any case and it is hard to believe it is not LaTeX. I am talking about Physical Review here. There are other journals that obviously use only or mostly LaTeX

Comment: It also uses `Plain TeX` concept for math...

Comment: From what I know Springer uses APP. I gave them LaTeX which they feed into APP, someway....

Answer (score 173):

I truly believe nothing comes close to TeX (and Friends, e.g. LaTeX, ConTeXt) when it comes to output quality.

Other DTP programs such as [Indesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html) (Adobe), [QuarkXPress](http://www.quark.com/Products/QuarkXPress/) (Quark) or [Scribus](http://scribus.net) (open source) offer a graphical interface and hence an easier learning curve, but they don't match up in terms of quality. Amongst many, let me just point the two most obvious quality advantages of TeX:

### Math typesetting

Typesetting maths correctly is very complex (symbols need to adjust in size, spaces are very specific, etc.), and only TeX gets it right. There are probably even better examples, but try obtaining something like the following in InDesign:

[image: math typesetting]

### Line and page breaking

Tex's algorithm is very complex and takes into account possible hyphens, widows, orphans, etc. to produce an output that is more elegant.

The best showcase of this I have found is a comparison posted by Roel Zinkstok of [Zink Typography](http://www.zinktypografie.nl/index.php?lang=en), reproduced below. On the comparison, Roel indicated with red dots lines with inter-word spacing that is out of proportion, a cardinal sin for typography, while the red circles indicate hyphens, which should be minimized:

[image: line breaking]

Comment: @mozartstraße More precisely, the red dots represents the lines with inter-word spacing (IWS) larger than 9pt. The count is reflected in the table below the showcase.

Comment: I do not remember where I read this, but it was pointed out a while ago that the Zink typography are probably somewhat pathological and designed to make TeX look especially good. I still think it is a good illustration, even if you have to take the quantitative analysis with a grain of salt.

Comment: @ach. It would be useful indeed to run tests on more texts, but I don't know how Roel was able to calculate things like IWS to perform these myself. I do agree that the small text widths increase the typesetting difficulty and exacerbate the limitations of each engine, but I think that this is still fair and required to make the comparison short (and it's entirely valid for newspaper output).

Comment: It also looks as though the `pdfTeX` output was made without the help of the `microtype` package.

Comment: @ach You are probably thinking of the comments to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110140/7674). The proof (as I would claim) that it's not a fair comparison can be found [here](http://scribd.com/doc/144579018/Test), which shows the result with tex's default settings on the first page and then increasing tweaks to mimic the example. @jon Actually, I do not think this output is achieved by using `microtype` but rather by allowing spaces to stretch and shrink much more than tex would normally permit (being as fussy as it is on this point).

Comment: AFAIK, InDesign also have several very complex linebreaking algorithms. One should choose a proper algorithm and tweak the arguments to get proper output.

Comment: @LeoLiu But one of LaTeX's benefits is that this tweaking is very simple. Load `microtype` with default settings, and 99,5 per cent of you typesetting have nice and pretty setting of the paragraphs. Nice page breaks on the other hand, especially if you are using `hyperref`, can be a challenge.

Comment: @Sveinung: I think it won't be difficult for InDesign. Even for TeX, tweaking penalties is not an easy job.

Comment: What about more recent versions of both InDesign and Word?

Comment: @Robert -- I agree about the with*out* `microtype` part entirely, but I'm not sure what you mean in the parentheses..?

Comment: @student: Adobe has stated openly (and in typeset form ;-) ) that InDesign uses precisely Knuth's linebreaking algorithms (per paragraph as opp. to per line). I have not used InDesign myself seriously, but from what I've seen done with it, I think it is a great typesetting system (ranking high together with QuarkXpress). Moreover, in this site there has been some discussion on grid-oriented typesetting design; maybe in this regard InDesign even ranks higher than TeX-based systems (not for lack of design excellence in TeX, but simply because it was not conceived with such a scenario in mind).

Comment: @jon What I mean is that TeX is (by default) quite strict in how much stretching or shrinking of spaces it tolerates. It would rather produce an overfull line than go beyond its limits of good taste. These tolerance limits are usually fine for longer lines but not for the rather short ones in the example.

Comment: @Marcos Most commercial products use a Knuth-Plass-_like_ algorithm, which usually mean they remove constraints to speed it up. Adobe even went as far as [to apparently patent theirs](http://www.google.com/patents/US6510441)... (don't get my started on stupid math / software patents). Regarding grid typesetting, it is actually quite simple in TeX, just not in LaTeX. Watch [Jean-Luc Doumont's "Quantum spaces: Designing pages on grids" presentation](http://river-valley.tv/quantum-spaces-designing-pages-on-grids/) if you want to know more.

Comment: @Robert -- Ah, right.  I should've realized that from experience, but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Xavier _"Most commercial products use a Knuth-Plass-_ like _algorithm"_: This is a bold statement, for which I would like to see some references. When Adobe introduced their (or rather Knuth's) multi-line composer in InDesign, this was one of the features that set it off from its main competitor QuarkXPress (which AFAIK still today uses a greedy single-line H&J algorithm) and all others.

Comment: @Robert My comment was poorly phrased. What I meant was: "more often than not, when commercial products claim to implement TeX / Knuth-Plasss line-breaking algorithm, they actually implement a Knuth-Plass-_like_ alhorithm". That being said, both InDesign and QuarkXPress (through the "Breakers" plugin) do implement a KP(-like) algorithm, so the statement was by chance not completely untrue IMHO. KP might even be [coming to the browser](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/typeset/) :)

Comment: I think that it would be nice to link to Roel's page with the original comparison. He deserves having link-credit for his work:

http://www.zinktypografie.nl/latex.php?lang=en

Comment: @Guy Done! The link was supposed to be there from the start, but I forgot the "http://" in the url which seem to have been enough to not show it :(

Comment: The spacing around the dashes (the glyph is the en-dash, but the semantic use is that of em-dashes) in the LaTeX example is much wider than the InDesign version. Could you adjust the dash-spacing in LaTeX and show the updated comparison?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I can't update the comparison unfortunately (it comes directly from [zinktypografie.nl](http://www.zinktypografie.nl/latex.php?lang=en) and no source was provided). But I believe there is no particular trick with the dash spacing: the white space just stretch or shrink depending on the line breaking point.

Comment: @Xavier I had about 20 minutes at hand so I redid your math typesetting example in MS Word: https://habrastorage.org/files/3d3/cfc/7db/3d3cfc7dbabb4d219924cc58be736dc5.png There are minor flaws here and there but I'd say that this is enough quality for a very big range of applications.

Answer (score 63):

A shameless plug: We are offering a professional typesetter (though open source) which is based on LuaTeX. If it is "equal or even better" than LaTeX is surely subjective.

Our focus is to bring the DTP world to automatic typesetting (database publishing). For example we have

- master pages based on arbitrary conditions
- text flow based on "frames"
- multi page tables including subtotals and repeating tablehead and tablefoot
- easy to install/use fonts
- grid based layout/typesetting
- ...

While TeX / LaTeX is focused on text documents (with or without math) our main application area is product catalogs, price lists and other documents that are created automatically from databases but have flexible and nice layouts.

https://www.speedata.de/

I'd like to invite everyone to try out or perhaps work on the software. Development never ends (as usual).

Comment: I'm intrigued by the grid-based support and text flowing. These are both regarded as 'hard' problems with TeX-based systems. How general are your solutions (in broad terms: not looking for anything commercially-sensitive)?

Comment: @JosephWright hard to discuss this in a comment... I believe your question is along the lines: "can we take the approach and throw it at LaTeX"? I'd say no, since I almost completely leave the TeX world. For example I save the text blocks and reformat them on demand (for example if columns are of different widths or of I need a parshape in the second column).

Comment: I wish I could get feedback for the downvote! Too much advertisement? (Hey, it's open source, so you can use it). Not a good answer? (I think it matches the question.) It would be nice if the downvoter could explain why this answer is a bad answer.

Comment: On 'generality' I was thinking for example that there are a few approaches to grid typesetting in TeX, but most (all?) have limitations, often related to display or math mode material. So I was wondering how generally you've been able to deal with this.

Comment: @JosephWright I have an invisible grid in the background with height of the grid cells of `\baselineskip` of the text font. Every object is placed in the grid (and thus integer multiple of `\baselineskip` from the top). There is still much to do but I will for example include an invisible "adjust to grid" marker that goes to the next cell. This part is currently under development.

Comment: Ah right: sounds conceptually the same as is done in `xor`, if done very differently. (I'm amazed at how short your files seem to be! Probably I miss something crucial.) Is there a demo document showing the input syntax?

Comment: This is *very* cool.  I wish you had made this a Python library rather than a Lua standalone.  I would have contributed.  The advantage to making it a library is that that other code can call into your code.

Comment: Here are some examples https://github.com/speedata/examples - also see the showcase at https://showcase.speedata.de

Answer (score 45):

[Troff](http://troff.org/) should definitely be mentioned for its simplicity. I normally use `LaTeX` for all my documents, but for some special cases (e.g. user manuals) `troff` (or its GNU version `groff`) is just the simpler way. It can also handle math using the preprocessing tool `eqn`. A nice comparison between `troff` and `LaTeX` can be found [here](http://www.schaffter.ca/mom/mom-03.html).

Comment: I just realised that the link I provided for the comparison actually is a macro package for `groff` which the author claims makes it comparable to `LaTeX`. I think I just found something to do for the weekend :)

Comment: Nice find! Can be a nice alternative to `LaTeX` for good looking automatically generated documents.

Comment: fyi, from wiki, `troff can trace its origins back to a text formatting program called RUNOFF` . see RUNOFF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RUNOFF `RUNOFF was the first computer text formatting program to see significant use.`

Comment: I used `ditroff` to typeset my thesis. And I believe `groff` has taken over some of $\TeX$ line-handling and math formatting techniques, so it should be comparable for text at least. But overall a troff document feels like assembler to $\LaTeX$' more structured approach. Lerned $'LaTeX$, and never looked back.

Comment: +1 for recommending Troff. For sophisticated typesetting, [Heirloom Troff](http://n-t-roff.github.io/heirloom/doctools.html) is a much better choice than Groff, offering support for microtypography, proper support for OpenType features, improved hyphenation, and - most importantly, native support for Type 1 fonts, TrueType and OpenType. Definitely a formidable contender with TeX for complex, accurate typesetting.

Answer (score 39):

[GNU TeXMacs](http://www.texmacs.org) is a WYSIWYG scientific structured document editor and typesetter. It used to require a TeX distribution but now it does not.

Here is a list of not so widely known typesetting systems that I found googling around, mostly work-in-progress (or work-used-to-be-in-progress):

- [cl-typesetting](http://www.fractalconcept.com/asp/cl-typesetting) is written in Common Lisp, which implies that its markup language is also Common Lisp. (Macro language, anyone?)
- The [Z format](http://z.departure.dk/z_format.html) looks like HTML, but is not.
- [Platypus](http://platypus.pz.org) commands look like `[list|bullet:{rarrow}]`
  . Written in Java.
- [Patoline](https://patoline.github.io), written in OCaml. Also handles SQL bibliography databases, and comes with Bibi, a bibfile to SQL converter written in Haskell. (The developers seem to be really keen on functional languages.) You have to build it from source. Commands look like a mixture of TeX, OCaml and new markup:

  ```
  (* #FORMAT FormatArticle *)
  \begin{genumerate}(AlphaLower, fun s -> [tT (s^". ")])
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \end{genumerate}
  \includeGraphics("pato.png")
  $$ a + b $$
  $ a + b $
  \Caml(
    let dr ()=
      [bB (fun _->
        [Drawing (drawing [Path (default,[rectangle (0.,0.) (10.,10.)])])]
     )]
  )
  ```

  <sub>Note that I have no idea if this code works, I just copied together parts of the manual.</sub>
- [SILE](http://sile-typesetter.org/) (Simon's Improved Layout Engine) is [written](https://github.com/simoncozens/sile) in Lua and uses the Harfbuzz shaping engine. It can typeset any XML input but also provides an input syntax similar to that of LaTeX:

  ```
  \begin[class=book,papersize=129mm x 198mm]{document}
  \include[src=examples/macros.sil]
  \script[src=packages/grid]
  \left-running-head{A Scandal in Bohemia}
  \right-running-head{\hfill{}Alexander Conan Doyle}
  \headline{A Scandal In Bohemia}

  \noindent To Sherlock Holmes she is always \em{the woman}.
  \footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

  \begin[family=Snell Roundhand]{font}
  Consequetur adipiscing elit.
  \end{font}
  \end{document}
  ```
- [Rinohtype](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype), written in Python. The input format is reStructuredText. See [an example input file](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/master/examples/restructuredtext/demo.txt).

Maybe more to come.

Comment: AFAIK, TeXmacs was never based on TeX; it uses various TeX algorithms but they are implemented independent of TeX. It uses TeX fonts, though, so that might be why it needed a TeX distribution in the past.

Comment: Nice edit, I searched for this just to add it :) But it seems that you already added it.

Comment: This Patoline thing looks promising, in case of active development. It can provide better error messages than TeX/LaTeX, due to types and safety checking.

Comment: The Patoline manual has not been available for about half a year (http://patoline.org/patobook.pdf), apparently because of a bug in Patoline, sadly.

Comment: Came back after using Texmacs: it is absolutely amazing for students who need to just do some homework (it's probably good for a lot of other things too). It needs little setup, has an intuitive and WYSIWYG interface design, and it just...works. Definitely better than going through LaTex esp. if you're in a pinch.

Answer (score 28):

First, add XyVision to the list of proprietary batch composition competitors.

Here's a bit of commentary I wrote up a couple of years ago, which still applies. It's also on the ConTeXt wiki.

https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.text.tex/8zugdUxw6dI/mu7Qzs4bQDYJ

Using a typesetting tool isn't like being a prisoner selecting a tool to dig their way out, it's more akin to being a galley slave....

So,

- using Quark is like being chained to an oar which is covered w/
  splinters and mostly broken at the other end and which will randomly
  break due to being poorly carved (Quark has crashed on me 183 times
  this year) leaving one adrift or run aground, or sometimes returning
  the vessel to its starting point (a few of those crashes have resulted
  in unrecoverable document corruption --- my autobackup folder may
  contain 2 or 3 GBs of files for a given iteration of a particular
  project each month) --- the oar can be smoothed somewhat and reinforced
  (by purchasing or finding XTensions, using XTags &c.) and periodically
  one is required to purchase a new oar (sometimes just after the
  previous one has been customized adequately). For some tasks, one can
  impress any graphic designer as a galley slave to ease the effort for
  others, but while charts are available, there are no automagic
  navigation options and every journey must be manually piloted.
- using InDesign is pretty much the same except the oar is smoother
  and stronger (it's crashed 29 times on me thus far this year), there
  aren't as many customization options and it's not quite as easy to find
  a candidate for impressment (though soon it'll be as easy as for
  Quark). Charts are available, but again, piloting is strictly manual.
- using Plain TeX one has to craft the vessel's oar oneself (as well
  as the rest of the vessel unless one is typesetting a clone of *The
  TeXbook*), but it's as sturdy and as nice a one as one's skills allow
  and can even be an engine which moves the vessel in and of itself ---
  it can be difficult or impossible to find people suitable to help w/
  either carving the oar or using it though, but once a given journey is
  worked out, the oar becomes magical and rows for itself except for when
  one runs into an unplanned for obstacle (the navigation charts are old
  ones and not often up-dated, with a lot of ``terra incognita''),
  allowing one an auto-pilot option for certain journeys, dependent upon
  one's skill.
- using ePlain, an oar is provided, can be customized, and can be
  enchanted and the charts are okay, but have a lot of ``terra
  incognita'' on them.
- using LaTeX, an oar is provided and there're lots of nifty
  customizations and improvements already available, and one can impress
  additional oars from CTAN, however on a semi-random basis, adding one
  oar will break other oars, sometimes leaving one adrift or run aground.
  One can enchant a set of oars to accomplish a given journey, easing the
  piloting requirement, and the navigation charts are decent and
  obstacles are fairly well-known.
- using ConTeXt, a very nice oar is provided, which has lots of
  customization options, but the navigational charts aren't easily read
  by a traditionally trained navigator at first, although they are fairly
  compleat and most journeys can be carefully worked out, but once one is,
  it is quite automatic and there's a good auto-pilot option.

Comment: your quotes around terra incognita give away your preference :P

Comment: +1 for style: certainly puts LaTex in context better than the usual table-of-features-I-then-need-to-look-up.

Answer (score 25):

I have recently discovered an awesome system [Typst](https://typst.app/) which is on par with LaTex with regard to typesetting quality, but superior in other aspects, i.e.,

1. previews your changes instantly.
2. has a consistent styling system for configuring everything from fonts and margins to the look of headings and lists.
3. easily collaborate in teams.
4. uses familiar programming constructs instead of hard-to-understand macros.
5. provides clear, understandable error messages.

You can watch a demo on the website https://typst.app/ to see points 1, 2, 3. Point 4 is illustrated by

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some side information, i.e.,

- Typst is funded by the Technical University of Berlin, the State of Berlin, and the European Union (through the European Social Funds). With such sponsors, it already has a promising future.
- The authors have [opened source](https://typst.app/blog/2023/beta-oss-launch/) the Typst compiler. They will open a public CTAN-like registry of Typst packages and templates down the road.
- The public beta will be released on March 21, 2023.
- The Discord server is https://discord.gg/2uDybryKPe. The authors are very supportive in answering your questions.

Comment: Will this be free for "ever"?

Comment: @projetmbc The authors will open source the Typst complier, so I guess it's free forever...

Comment: @projetmbc The authors has opened source Typst. Please see [here](https://typst.app/blog/2023/beta-oss-launch/).

Comment: To be fair with Overleaf collaborating on LaTeX is possible too.

Comment: Re-reading this, Typst typesetting quality is not yet on par with LaTeX. There are a few issues left e.g. https://github.com/typst/typst/issues/439

Comment: @user202729 At the current stage of Typst, I agree that it has a lot of typesetting issues and is not on par with LaTex...

Comment: @projetmbc update: typst compiler can be found at https://github.com/typst/typst

Answer (score 23):

A new alternative is [Patoline](https://patoline.github.io), which is still in an early development stage but the goal is to be a modern digital typesetting system.

As for the LaTeX compatibility one can describe the Patoline compiler as

> Obviously, a related (but much smaller) project is the Patoline compiler, which compiles a mixed Wiki/LaTeX/Ocaml syntax into a variety of output formats, including traditional PDF files, but also web servers that deliver dynamic contents, synchronized for instance with a talk.

The [documentation](https://patoline.github.io/#documentation) includes a PhD thesis and a description of the syntax which was produced using Patoline, and which looks to me as an amateur in typesetting pretty good:

[image]

Comment: However, Patoline has many flaws that make it very hard to use at the moment. As well, it introduces some concepts that I don't quite like. I wonder if Xavier and his collaborators manage to make it as tweakable as TeX is, in the sense that any feature it has has to be tunable, and in particular, easy to disable.

Comment: @tohecz: I have unfortunately not found the time to try it out myself. Still, I am hoping for an alternative to LaTeX which keeps the good features but replaces the 'programming language' with something more reasonable. LuaTeX is definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: That's another point: OCaml doesn't look like a good choice...

Comment: sorry I used the wrong name in the 1st comment, the main developer is of course Pierre-Etienne, not Xavier.

Answer (score 19):

While LaTeX is the markup language of choice in many scientific and scholarly circles (especially in the fields of mathematics, computer science, physics, and astronomy), some scholars are starting to write papers using new markup languages tailored for the web. [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is one of them. It is very versatile and it can be easily extended to satisfy the needs of scientific writing. The advantage of using Markdown (or similar) instead of LaTeX is that we are writing on the web more than ever. Thus, it makes sense to use a web native typesetting format. For those who would like to use both Markdown and Latex on the web, [Authorea](https://www.authorea.com) (full disclosure, I am a co-founder) is an online social authoring platform that allows articles to be edited in both formats simultaneously. Authorea also renders and compiles LaTeX and MathML equations to the web, in addition to PDF.

Comment: LaTeX is not only markup but also typesetting. And welcome to TeX.sx!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! That platform looks quite intriguing, indeed. Do you have any relationship to the company that runs it (apart from being a user)?

Comment: hi Jake- yes I am the co-founder of Authorea (and a user, since I still write papers in Astronomy + Information Science). We have a couple of thousand users and the vast majority of them writes in LaTeX.

Comment: @user32799: Thanks for the reply. When posting an answer promoting a product you're affiliated with, that affiliation should be disclosed (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Could you edit your post to include that information?

Comment: hi Jake- I just updated my .sx profile information with my affiliation. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoPepe Wondering if you implemented LaTeX for the web or anything like that, "Authorea also renders and compiles LaTeX and MathML equations to the web", and what that was like.

Answer (score 17):

TeX and friends maybe still the best. There are some alternative and results are various. I do not really use any of them, but kind of know there existence.

- [Lout](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lout)
- [ANT](http://ant.berlios.de/)

Comment: Another one: [asciidoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/)

Comment: there was also chi-writer. no longer around. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChiWriter

Comment: ANT is an impressive codebase, especially the support they have for OTF. Also, the embedded scripting languages is a huge win. Unfortunately it depends on archaic versions of libraries and the language, so it won’t build on current systems. The most recent post on their mailing list is from 2010 so I guess it could be considered unmaintained.

Comment: I'm really interested in whether Lout and Ant have ever been used. Can you give examples/sample output if there's any? (Apart from their respective user manuals, of course.) I'm also interested in their "stories", why they are unmaintained, what happened with the author, etc.

Comment: Follow the example in Lout's user manual will do. Lout is still under development, it just [released 3.40](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lout-users/2013-06/msg00016.html). Jeffrey (the author) does not use source version control.  But you could always look at the [mailing list](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lout-users/), it is a low volume list but active. He plan his next typesetting engine [Nonpareil](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~jeff/nonpareil/), but seems not much news yet. Main drawback that Lout doesn't support unicode. Not sure about ANT.

Comment: @qunying, "not using a source version control system" is a *very* bad idea, and makes me stay away... Linux did pull it off for a long time, but then again, Linus is Linus. And he ended up creating [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software))...

Comment: @vonbrand, I don't like it either, but it is the author's way.

Answer (score 12):

As long as you don't need mathematical typesetting, you actually can find *better* than TeX with [Heirloom Documentation Tools](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/doctools.html). Not only does it provide Knuth's algorithm for formatting paragraphs; it also allows to compute spacing by mixing three systems (interletters spacing, interwords spacing, imperceptible change in the shapes of the glyphs). Thus you can work with *constant* space between words! Selecting a font among various kinds of fonts is much easier and quicker than with TeX. I have been using it for years while my colleagues use LaTeX; they wouldn't have the idea to only think their documents can be on a par with mine. If you are interested in typography, then Heirloom version of troff is definitely the way to do.

**edit:** Since I first wrote this answer, it looks like new pieces of software have appeared. I just heard about [utroff](http://utroff.org) which seems to come from *Heirloom troff*; I will very certainly have a look at it and probably use it now because *Heirloom troff* doesn't seem to be actively maintained and may be difficult to compile.

Answer (score 5):

I recently found this page: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-alternatives

Which lists:

> #### Active projects
>
> - Patoline
>
> Patoline is a typesetting system written in OCaml and using a mix of
> TeX-like syntax and “escape” to OCaml to provide typesetting control.
> Patoline aims for a module design, and fast numerical processing.
>
> - SILE https://sile-typesetter.org/examples/packages.html
>
> SILE is a typesetting system written in Lua and using the HarfBuzz
> font shaper. It’s input syntax is somewhat inspired by LaTeX, for
> example
>
> \begin{document} Hello SILE! \end{document}
>
> is a valid SILE document (notice the lack of a preamble here).
>
> - Speedata Publisher
>
> Speedata Publisher is like SILE written in Lua, but uses LuaTeX (not
> pure Lua) to provide the “back-end”. This means it does feature a tiny
> TeX-based wrapper, but once that has handed over to Lua, TeX is not
> involved. Speedata Publisher is particularly well-suited to some areas
> in which TeX is less successful, for example more image-rich
> documents.
> -Lout
>
> Lout is a batch document formatter invented by Jeffrey H. Kingston. It
> reads a high-level description of a document similar in style to LaTeX
> Lout copies some of its formatting algorithms from TeX but uses a
> high-level functional programming language, instead of a macro
> language as its customisation language. Lout has never had the user
> base of LaTeX, but is still maintained and was released around the
> same time as LaTeX2e in the early 1990’s.
>
> - troff/nroff/groff
>
> groff The *roff family of typesetters pre-date TeX and influenced its
> design. They have always been distributed as part of Unix and
> Unix-like systems such as linux. Most notably man pages are typeset
> with this system.
>
> #### Historical projects
>
> - The ANT typesetting system

Answer (score 4):

The open source software `TUSTEP` is developed and used at the German university of Tübingen and is apparently mostly used for

- "literary / critical editing"
- "bibliographies, indexes, dictionaries, encyclopedias"

(copied from the project webpage http://www.tustep.uni-tuebingen.de/tustep_eng.html). The pdf manual seems to by typeset with `TUSTEP` and `Ghostscript`.

The software seems to be operational since 1971 if I understood an ai translation of http://www.itug.de/index.php?id=58 correctly. The most recent version apparently was published in 2022.

I have never used the software and I do not personally know anybody who uses it.

Answer (score 3):

[Pollen](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pollen), written in Racket (of the Lisp family). The primary focus is web-based typography (and no math so far), but it can also support other formats such as pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Scientific Word can be another alternative software for scientists:
[http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/sw.html~mainFrame](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/sw.html%7EmainFrame)

The company behind this software is MacKichan Software, Inc., and went out of business on July 1, 2021 ([http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/sw.html~mainFrame](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/sw.html%7EmainFrame)):

> Sales have ceased for Scientific WorkPlace, Scientific Word, and
> Scientific Notebook
>
> MacKichan Software, Inc., after providing word processing software for
> those who speak the language of mathematics for forty years (under
> several names), closed its doors on June 30, 2021. This marks the end
> of sales and support for the MacKichan Software products.
>
> All owners of Scientific WorkPlace, Scientific Word, or Scientific
> Notebook should have a serial number that was included in their
> purchase. This number is also included in the license file for your
> installation as the last line in the file. If you need to install your
> software on a new or different computer, you will need to re-activate
> the software on that computer using that serial number. The software
> can be activated as before, using the Help/Activate menu item. This
> contacts the MacKichan Software licensing server, which we will keep
> running for at least two years.
>
> Thirty-day trials of all of our products are discontinued. Trial
> serial numbers will no longer work to activate the software.
>
> Sites with permanent site licenses will, of course, be free to use
> Scientific WorkPlace, Scientific Word, and/or Scientific Notebook as
> long as they like. Those sites that have paid for maintenance with
> home-use satellite licenses can continue, but will be unable to create
> new satellite licenses after their maintenance agreement expires.
>
> We expect to make Scientific Word an open source product eventually.
> Since both Scientific WorkPlace and Scientific Notebook contain the
> proprietary computer algebra system MuPAD, they cannot be made open
> source. When the open source project for Scientific Word is
> established, an announcement will be made here.
>
> We hope to make version 5.5 of Scientific Word available in the
> future. It currently contains several components that are licensed and
> not owned by MacKichan Software. These components need to be removed,
> and our intention is then to make Scientific Word version 5.5 open
> source.
>
> Barry MacKichan President  MacKichan Software, Inc.
>
> July 1, 2021
>
> The latest released version of these products is 6.1.2. To update your
> program to the latest release, click [here](http://www.mackichan.com/techtalk/v60/1002updatesv6.htm).  The same page also
> contains links to the installers for version 5.5 and the manuals for
> versions 5.5 and 6.

Comment: Scientific Word comprises a TeX distribution along with a quasi-WYSIWYG front end. The code it generates is (mostly) LaTeX. I'm thus doubtful that Scientific Word can be considered a alternative to LaTeX. Separately, the software hasn't seen an upgrade in years and years. The current version, numbered 5.5, has been around since at least 2007 (and probably even longer). A software package that's been around essentially unchanged for more than seven years is functionally obsolete, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Mico As far as I agree, the same thing can essentially be said about TeX.

Comment: @Gaussler - Version 6 of Scientific Word has been released quite recently; I'm sure the long-suffering users of SW were jubilant. I don't agree that SW's situation is comparable to that of TeX. (i) TeXLive has been every year for many years now. (ii) While "Plain TeX" is frozen, that's not the case for pdfLaTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, and lots and lots of packages for pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaTeX. (iii) LaTeX2e was also nearly frozen for many years, but got a significant update as of 1/1/2015.

Comment: @Mico Still, the pdfTeX backend has remained dominant and frozen since forever. Also, you compare Plain TeX - a *format* - to LuaTeX and XeTeX - two *engines*.

Comment: @Gaussler - Sorry I wasn't sufficiently clear: By "Plain TeX", I mean both the "engine" (without eTeX extensions) and the "format" (as laid out in the Texbook). Does that help?

Comment: I had no idea Plain also referred to the engine. Is that really standard?

Comment: @Gaussler - I'm no good at linguistic quibbles. Can't vouch for what "standard" terminology may be. All I can hope for is that I've clarified what *I* meant to say.

Comment: @Gaussler [3 months](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/?root=pdftex) is forever? [Details](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php?root=pdftex&view=rev).

Comment: Related to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/128553.

Comment: @mico **Version 6 of Scientific Word has been released quite recently; I'm sure the long-suffering users of SW were jubilant.** It turned out that Version 6 of SW was a disaster and huge failure. So much so that the whole company went bankrupt about 2 years ago.  They changed to using XML and spend 8 years and could not make it work.  V 5.5 was great. But the company was stupid and decided to change to XML.

Comment: @Nasser - Indeed, while users' hopes, back in 2015, for Version 6 of SWP were very high initially, these hopes were quickly, and bitterly, disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

R Markdown runs on the TeX distribution when using `kntr` to create PDFs. But, to type in it requires less code memorization since R produces default YAML headers when you load up a new document.

Comment: It doesn't provide better typesetting, since TeX does the typesetting. It doesn't provide equal typesetting, because it provides less control on the output than typing in TeX.