# How to embed Javascript in LaTeX Beamer?

Tags: beamer, javascript

I'm wondering if it is possible to add javascript animations in LaTeX Beamer, e.g. figures created with [C3](http://c3js.org/) or [D3](http://d3js.org/)? As far as I remember the animate packages uses javascript in order to display (and probably run) the videos embedded in the document. There is a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-document-level-javascript-in-latex-documents) on embedding JavaScript in LaTeX on StackExchange, but the post focuses on document-level Javascript in a PDF (no mentions on including third party libraries such as D3).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not everybody is fluent with Javascript here; can you be more precise about what C3 and D3 mean?

Comment: for presentations that would be great! Unfortunately that basically requires embedding a browser viewport in the PDF. I would also be curious to know if that is possible. However you could also produce your slides using something like [remark](http://remarkjs.com) which runs in the browser already allowing you to embed such videos with an `iframe`

Comment: I think there is no drawing canvas object provided by AdobeReader's JavaScript engine which would be the basic requirement for runtime-generated graphics and animations.

Comment: it is possible d3 can generate svg object, so as long as you insert svg to pdf, you are good to go. The problem is then; does latex have a JS engine? I am assuming graphic objects are compiled on-the-fly.

Comment: Just for reference to the comment by @AlexG: the [Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Guide](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf) by Adobe.

Comment: try this out:
[A previous thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99275/is-there-any-solution-to-include-java-applets-in-presentations-beamers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is embedded in the comments above. At the moment, there is no way to use JavaScript libraries like D3 and C3 as is; however, you could do similar things, if you wanted to write the code from scratch or modify those libraries to use the PDF object model OR export their graphics for use in LaTeX (see [d3js/SVG Export demo](http://d3export.housegordon.org/))

Notes:

1. LaTeX allows us to create PDF or PostScript (.ps) files
2. PDF has its own document object model (DOM) (as referenced in the [Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Guide](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf) p. 22).  In other words, PDF supports JavaScript, but not the Browser DOM, which is the way the Browser displays lines, text and images on a page.
3. D3 and C3 use the browser's DOM to draw on the page